# Android: Passing data from surfaceView to its parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, surfaceview

I am having trouble sending info from a surfaceView class to its parent class

the overlay activity sets its view as a drawing panel:

```
public class Overlay extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_Overlay);
       drawingPanel dPanel = new drawingPanel(this);
       setContentView(dPanel);

    }
}
```

then in the drawing panel:

```
public class drawingPanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    Context context = context;
    public Player(Context context, int num) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
       super(context);
       this.context = context;
       SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
       holder.addCallback(this);
    }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
       if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
           //send info to Overlay that drawingPanel was touched
       }
    }
}
```

When surfaceView is touched, I want to send that info to Overlay. I can't simply use onTouchEvent in the Overlay activity because I need to draw stuff with drawingPanel. My main goal is to hide/show the action bar when the screen is touched while using a surfaceView. if there is another way to achieve that, please state so below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line to `onCreate` method of your `Overlay` class

```
   dPanel.setActivity(this);
```

And implementing `setActivity()` in the `drawingPanel` class like this:

```
public void setActivity(Activity overlayActivity) {
    mActivity = overlayActivity;
}
```

This way, you can use `mActivity` to reference your Activity and call public methods to "hide/show the action bar", like:

```
mActivity.getActionBar().hide();
```

and,

```
mActivity.getActionBar().show();
```

Comment: Dannie's code works! (for future readers) his last two lines are pseudo code, so here's what I'm using in the onTouchEvent method:    if(mActivity.getActionBar().isShowing()) mActivity.getActionBar().hide();
   else mActivity.getActionBar().show();

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the answer accordingly.